# Change child element cursor

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `@material-ui/core: "4.0.1"`

Using a `TextField` component and trying to change the cursor to `'not-allowed'`.

Simple code as below

```
<TextField style={{cursor:'not-allowed'}}
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        margin="normal"
        disabled={true}
      />
```

But since the `TextField` it self have other component inside, disabled cursor icon only appear in top part of the ui (not on top of actual text area) as below

[image]

Can see two divs and one input control under TextField

[image]

Tried using glamor to overwrite the class as below but no luck

```
const styles = glamor.css({
  cursor:'not-allowed'
})

function MyStyledDiv({ ...rest}) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles} ${'MuiInputBase-input'}`}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Testing</p>
      <MyStyledDiv>
      <TextField style={{cursor:'not-allowed'}}
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        margin="normal"
        disabled={true}
      />
      </MyStyledDiv>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this

Comment: I am not sure does this a proper way but try directly with `id selector` inside css:
`#standard-name { cursor:'not-allowed'; }`. Or give a `class` to `TextField` and select it: `.myClass > #standard-name { cursor:'not-allowed'; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the styling to the `inputProps` prop:

```
<TextField
   id="standard-name"
   label="Name"
   margin="normal"
   disabled={true}
   inputProps={{style: {cursor:'not-allowed'}}}
/>
```